# Python OpenCV Through R

Tags: python, r, opencv, reticulate

I'm trying to call OpenCV for Python through R. I installed reticulate, which is an R interface to Python. I installed `opencv` using

```
conda_install('r-reticulate', 'opencv')
```

Everything appeared to install fine, and `conda_install` has a flag that is set to TRUE by default to include the `conda-forge` repo. When I run

```
reticulate::py_module_available("cv2")
```

I get FALSE. I'm not sure what is going wrong. I'm using `Reticulate 1.18 REPL -- A Python interpreter in R.` and `Python 3.6.12`.

Comment: You might also consider the `opencv` R package for access to some of the same functionality: https://github.com/ropensci/opencv

Comment: @JonSpring Thanks! But I have some Python code from a collaborator that I'd like to call within a larger R script.

Answer (score 0):

just try this,

```
library(reticulate)

cv2 <- import("cv2") 

img <- cv2$imread("image.jpg", cv2$IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

image.jpg is everything you'd like to try.
and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue using Reticulate. Once you've loaded the Reticulate package, try using `pip` from the R terminal:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

This worked for me and everything loaded as expected.

[image]